# Using a tangent-space normal map with world-space normals

Tags: opengl, glsl, normals

I'm working on deferred shading in GLSL. I have all of my model normals in world space, and the positions as well. The whole thing is working exactly as it should with just the world-space normals of the polygons, but I'm unsure of how to add normal mapping. I know it's recommended to do lighting in view-space, and I've tried that but I couldn't get even a quarter as far with that as I have with world-space. All I have left to fix now is adding normals. I have a regular normal map, which is in tangent-space. I've tried the following:

1. Multiplying the world-space normal by the normal-map didn't seem to work.
2. I tried adding the normal-map's normals, even though I knew that wouldn't work.

At this point I'm not really sure what else to try. Is there any easy way to do this?

Normal-rendering frag shader:

```
#ifdef NORMALMAP
uniform sampler2D m_Normals;
#endif

varying vec3 normal;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 normals;
    #ifdef NORMALMAP
        normals = normalize(normal * (texture(m_Normals, texCoord).xyz));
    #else
        normals = normal;
    #endif
    gl_FragColor = vec4(normals, 1.0);
}
```

The variable "normal" is the world-space normal passed in from the vertex shader.

Comment: Why are you multiplying a normal by a value in a normal map? The normal map gives you the normal. The only thing you would really want to multiply it by is a matrix that transforms it into a different coordinate space (e.g. tangent->world). Of course your normal maps are already in world-space according to your question, so they should not (and cannot reasonably) be transformed; do your lighting in world-space to make things simpler.

Comment: I am doing my lighting in world-space. That's the problem. My code reconstructs position from depth buffer in world-space. My light positions are all in normal space. As I said, it works perfectly until I add in the normal maps, because the normal maps are in tangent space, as all are. I have the polygon's WORLD-SPACE normals, but a TANGENT-SPACE normal map. My question is how to convert tangent to world. My apologies, the title was a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My light positions are all in normal space.

I do not know what "normal space" means here be honest. There are "normal spaces" in mathematics, but that is quite unrelated and there is no standard coordinate space referred to as "normal space."

> My question is how to convert tangent to world.

Your polygon's world-space normal is inadequate to solve this problem (in fact, you need a per-vertex normal). To transform from tangent-space to object-space you need three things:

1. your object-space normal vector
2. a vector representing the change in texture s coordinates
3. a vector representing the change in texture t coordinates

Those three things together form the tangent-space -> object-space change of basis matrix (usually referred to as ***TBN*** because the vectors are called Tangent, Bitangent and Normal).

However, you do not want object-space normals in this question, so you need to multiply that matrix by your model matrix so that it skips over object-space and goes straight to world-space. Likewise, if your normal vector is already in world-space you need to transform it back to object-space. It is possible that object-space and world-space are the same in this case particularly since we are only dealing with a 3x3 matrix here (no translation). But I cannot be sure from the description you have given.

One last thing to note, in this case you want the inverse of the traditional TBN matrix. Traditionally it is used to transform vectors ***into*** tangent-space, but you want to transform them ***out***. The inverse of a rotation matrix is the same as its transpose, so all you really have to do is put those 3 vectors across your rows instead of columns<sup>**1**</sup>.

*<sup>**1**</sup>That assumes that your T, B and N vectors are at right-angles. That is not necessarily the case since they are derived from your texture coordinates. It is all going to come down to what you use to compute your Tangent and Bitangent vectors; a lot of software will re-orthogonalize them for you.*

Comment: I can easily get the object-space normals (I converted them to world on the vertex shader so it's a simple matter of taking that bit out), and I have a TBN matrix in my vertex shader. To be brutally honest, I have no idea how I didn't think about simply transposing that matrix. I feel rather stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, judging by your new information, I think what you want is this: `normals = normalize (TBN * texture (m_Normals, texCoord).xyz) * vec3 (0.5) + vec3 (0.5);` That last part (* 0.5 + 0.5) may or may not be necessary depending on what kind of texture you are storing your normals in - if it is floating-point or SNORM you will not need it, but if it is simply `GL_RGB` you will (and you will need * 2 - 1 in your lighting pass to unpack it). This is because you have to deal with normals with negative values.

Comment: Using that exact bit of code there, it's giving me perfect normals - in view space? In my final deferred shading shader, I have the camera's inverse WorldViewMatrix, which I have successfully used to translate view stuff to world stuff. Would I be able to simple call something like this in the final shading pass?
`m_InverseViewMatrix * vec4(normals, 0.0)`
to move it into world-space? Or is there a big no-no I'm missing involving translating normals with a vector like that?

Comment: You wouldn't want to do that. You should just output the normal in world-space to begin with. By the way, I actually forgot one step in that code (the normals are currently in ***object-space***), and that was to transform it to world-space. You should consider `normals = normalize (Model * TBN * texture (m_Normals, texCoord).xyz) * vec3 (0.5) + vec3 (0.5)`. Or whatever the matrix you have to transform from object-space to world-space is called (I assumed `Model`, but some people call it `World`).

Comment: The normals it's giving me are not in world space though. As I move the camera, the normals facing me change to blue (z-forward), those facing "up" change to green, and so on, instead of remaining static. I may just completely restart on this lighting system and give view-space another go, because it seems things would be a fair bit easier that way.

Comment: Well, the TBN matrix by itself is supposed to be object-space. If you are multiplying it directly by that and the normals are changing as the camera does then your matrix itself is bad. It is entirely possible that you forgot to invert your matrix.